# fb:live-stream will not work unless "post to Facebook" is checked?

Tags: facebook, web-applications

We had a live-stream where we would chat with our users during a live event. 3 weeks ago it stopped working when we un-check "post to Facebook" we no longer can interact with out users meaning no one can see us in the chat. it seems we HAVE to check post to Facebook in order to interact with the livestream however we don't want every comment we make to post to our page,.

Any ideas?

Comment: This relates to programming... how?

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same issue.  You may want to subscribe to this thread in the official support forum, in case they resolve it there?  They say it's "Assigned" but it is only "Mid-pri" and hasn't been updated since 9/23.  http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/172406742840270?browse=search_4e8526363e1cf8f42318199

If you have another app that you know to work in the interim, there are a lot of interested folks.  We've gone to an embedded IRC solution until they fix it.